# Whats wrong with my code and why dosen't it replace eplace "EVERY INSTANCE" of the capital letter G with Gb,

Tags: linux, unix, sed

My code:

```
df -h | sed 's/G/Gb/' >> $2
```

The output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              29Gb  5.5G   22G  21% /
devtmpfs              757M  196K  757M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 757M  436K  757M   1% /dev/shm
```

The output I need:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              29Gb  5.5Gb   22Gb  21% /
devtmpfs              757M  196K  757M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 757M  436K  757M   1% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the global flag

```
df -h | sed 's/G/Gb/g' >> $2
```

Your original code changes the first match of the pattern. Adding a "g" (global) after the ending "/" makes it global - changes all matching instances. Not this could have unintended consequences e.g. If any of the volumne names comtained a "G", that would be changed too.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert M to Mb and K to Kb as well:

```
df -lh | perl -pe 's/([0-9])(G)( )/\1Gb\3/g; s/([0-9])(M)( )/\1Mb\3/g; s/([0-9])(K)( )/\1Kb\3/g'
```